# Check if a variable is in a Set of Strings

Tags: arrays, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new with Thymeleaf.
I would know how can i check if  var is in ('str1', 'str2', 'str3').
like this

```
 <span th:if="${entry.value} in ['fr','en','bl']">
```

How to do it with Thymeleaf dialect ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
<span th:if="${#arrays.contains({'fr','en','bl'}, entry.value)}">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a good resource** to check on the subject. Hope it helps.

[thymeleaf-strings-utility-method-for-string-objects](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/thymeleaf-strings-utility-method-for-string-objects/)

```
${#strings.contains(str1,'target_string_here')}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm trying to do this ${#strings.contains(${entry.value}+'', 'fr,en,bl')}